# What legendary gem effects are procced by pet attacks?

Tags: diablo-iii

At one point it was common knowledge that the only Legendary Gem that procced from pet attacks was [Pain Enhancer](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Pain_Enhancer). After some digging around after an in-game revelation, I noticed that the [Gem of Effacious Toxin](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Gem_of_Efficacious_Toxin) will also proc from pet attacks. What other gems proc from pet attacks, if any?

Edit: I am aware that the GET may be a special case due to its activation text stating *All enemies hit*, rather than *on hit*, but I wish to be thorough.

Comment: I thought anything that procs could be from pet attacks.

Comment: you thought wrong. most, if not all, 'on hit' effects will not proc from pet attacks.